# How to make mutually Exclusive checkBoxes in WPF DataGrid Columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am having following DataGrid Code

```
<UserControl x:Class="abc.WPFApp.UCGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WPFtoolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:abc.WPFApp">

    <UserControl.Resources>
<!--Restrict editing based on IsVariable-->
        <Style x:Key="CheckBoxCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVariable}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
        <WPFtoolkit:DataGrid x:Name="UCdataGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                                     CellStyle="{StaticResource defaultCellStyle}"
                                                     RowStyle="{StaticResource defaultRowStyle}"
                                                     ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource defaultDataGridColumnHeader}"
                                                     SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                                                     RowBackground="White" 
                                                     AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue"
                                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended" RowHeaderWidth="20"
                                     CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                                     CanUserResizeColumns="True" AllowDrop="True" KeyUp="UCGridKeyUp" >
            <WPFtoolkit:DataGrid.Columns>


<WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dgChkRepeatingData" Binding="{Binding Path=MasterDataFlag}" MaxWidth="135" MinWidth="80"
                                     Header="Repeating data" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="{Binding (IsVariable)}" 
                                     EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxCellStyle}"
                                      >
                </WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                <WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn MaxWidth="100" Header="Max Element" x:Name="dgChkMaxElement"
                                                   Binding="{Binding Path=MaxElement}" MinWidth="70" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxCellStyle}">
                </WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                <WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn MaxWidth="100" Header="In For Loop" x:Name="dgChkInForLoop"
                                                   Binding="{Binding Path=InForLoop}" MinWidth="70" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxCellStyle}">
                </WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgXPath" Binding="{Binding Path=XPath}" Header="XPath" Width="500"
                                               Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsVariable}"
                                               EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextBoxCellStyle}"/>
</WPFtoolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        </WPFtoolkit:DataGrid>
```

This user control Grid comprised if three Columns which should be mutually exclusive.
I want to achieve this by creating Triggers in XAML itself , How can we do this ?

Comment: The problem you run into is explicitly setting a value overrides any trigger values.  As you are doing databinding is there any reason you cannot implement the exclusivity in the backend model object

Comment: Why would you do this? Its Part of the application Logic and belongs into the ViewModel rather then into the View. You should really not be using Triggers in XAML to implement app logic/constrains.

Comment: as these checkBoxes are not accessible from the corresponding C# file, How can we achieve this using C# Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use radiobuttons with a checkbox style to achieve mutually exclusive behavior. If you have any problem binding radiobuttons: [radiobutton-binding](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&tl=en&u=http://blog.gioos.com/wpf/2010/11/15/wpf-radiobutton-binding.html)

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding VMProperty}" GroupName="IsSelectedGroup">
    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RadioButton}}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
</RadioButton>
```

But, i agree with Jaster. If you have each row binded to a ViewModel, the place to put this logic restriction is the ViewModel.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Look-less controls make it easy to swap out the style and achieve the expected behavior regardless of what implementation is used in the backend. I added the style required based off your suggestion - works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

i am trying by creating such Style for 3rd column "InFor" But it is not at all working

```
<Style x:Key="mutualCheckInForLoop" TargetType="{x:Type WPFtoolkit:DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type WPFtoolkit:DataGridCell}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=dgChkRepeatingData,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=dgChkMaxElement,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```